# How can I know when my QItemDelegate is the last item in the list?

Tags: qt, qt5, qitemdelegate

My custom item delegate overrides this function:

```
void TileToolDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
```

Everything works fine and draws fine except, for some reason, '`option.viewItemPosition`' is always **QStyleOptionViewItem::ViewItemPosition::Invalid**

I'm trying to check if the item is the last item in the list:

```
//Draw the dropshadow, if this is the final item in the list.
if(option.viewItemPosition == QStyleOptionViewItem::ViewItemPosition::End
|| option.viewItemPosition == QStyleOptionViewItem::ViewItemPosition::OnlyOne)
{
    //...
}
```

Debugging shows me that for every item, the result is **ViewItemPosition::Invalid**. =(...

Is my model supposed to provide those details? If so, how?
My model inherits QAbstractListModel, and the view is a QListView.

Note: Because I don't know why this isn't working, I'm just cheating by comparing the QModelIndex to `0` and `rowCount()-1`, but I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand **viewItemPosition** is not set in the paint event of the QListView. I have checked it [here](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistview.cpp). In my sandbox it also returns me 0 no matter if the item on the top or at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! When you say, "As far as you understand", do you mean it's *supposed* to be 0, or that this is a bug on Qt's part?

Comment: I suppose that paint event of the QListView should set this attribute and pass it further to the paint event of the delegate but it doesn't happen. If it is true then it is possible feature request.

Comment: I guess I should link to the bug report here, for posterity: [QTBUG-47755](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47755)